# Camel .contains() not search values from properties file

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to search string inside the files, I have used below java code search string that working as i expected,

```
.when(body().convertToString().contains("mytext"))
```

if i need to change the search string i have to recomple code again, So i try to load search string from the properties file as below
I defined `findme='mytext'` inside the property file but that will not search string with "properties:{{findme}}"

```
.when(body().convertToString().contains("properties:{{findme}}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be :

```
.when(body().convertToString().contains("{{findme}}"))
```

From [Apache Camel documentation on properties](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) :

> **Syntax**
>
> The syntax to use Camel's property placeholder is to use `{{key}}` for
>   example `{{file.uri}}` where file.uri is the property key. You can use
>   property placeholders in parts of the endpoint URI's which for example
>   you can use placeholders for parameters in the URIs.

Comment: thanks. i already tried `{{fineme}}`is not working, note:I can load properties in to from("properties:{{myvalue}}") and thats working as i expected, only contains("{{findme}}") not working for me

Comment: You probably have a problem with your placeholder definition. Could you please provide the code for your placeholder ?

Comment: PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
  pc.setLocation("myfile.properties");
  context.addComponent("properties", pc);

Comment: Use the simple language it has a contains and properties function

Comment: Where is `myfile.properties` file located in your project ?

Comment: @MickaëlB  in the classpath

Comment: @user881703 Could you be more precise ?

Comment: @ClausIbsen simple language worked for me. Thank you `when(simple("${bodyAs(String)} contains ${properties:findme:default}"))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `contains` will do the expected `simple` expression. You should be explicit about the contains value.

```
when(body().convertToString().contains(exchangeProperty("findme")))
```